# chrome extension content script cannot be loaded when using relative path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I met a strange problem which bothered me a lot.

To use the the content scripts, the manifest file is set as:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ ... ],
        "js": [ "a.js", "b.js"]
    }
]
```

a.js and b.js are put in the root directory of the project. It worked. To organize the project, I moved the two file into a folder, then modified manifest as:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ ... ],
        "js": [ "lib/a.js", "lib/b.js"]
    }
]
```

Then the extension cannot work and open the dev tool, the content scripts are all empty. If I revoke, then it works again. So what's wrong?

Thank you all!

Comment: The extension should work without problems if the scripts are in a folder. Be sure that you reloaded the extension and that the folders are really in the extension root directory.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin , thanks for your reply, I finally figured out what's wrong. I was using a "reload extension" chrome extension to reload the modified extension. When I reload manually from the chrome://extensions/, it works. I have uninstalled the problematic reload extension...

Comment: Great! Created an answer if someone else will face this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension should work without problems if the scripts are in a folder.

You may do the following to solve this:

1. Try to reloaded the extension. Navigate to `chrome://extensions/` and click the `Reload` link near the extension;
2. Be sure that the relative folders are really in the extension root directory;
3. If you're using [Extensions Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid?hl=en) and made some modification to `manifest.json` file, then you must manually reload the extension in `chrome://extensions/`. Extensions Reloader does not reload changes from `manifest.json`, but mostly the content script file changes.