# How can I detect in google chrome extension that I am logged in to another website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a web application and I've made an additional google chrome extension for it. If I am logged in to the website, how to detect it in google chrome extension, so I do not have to log again in extension. When I am logged in to the site, I want the extension to detect that I am logged in to the site and logged in automatically to the extension.

I have the following error:

> Could not load JavaScript file "content.js" for content script.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "EXTENSION",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://*.app.com/*"  ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
}],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "https://*/",
   "http://*/",
   "*://*.app.com/*",
    "storage"
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**content.js**

```
if(chrome && chrome.storage){
  chrome.storage.sync.get('token', function(result){

    const item = result['access_token'];
    console.log(item);

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(item, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
}


var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'test'});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, port) {
  console.log(msg);
});
port.postMessage('from-iframe');
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('popup got', msg, 'from', sender);
  sendResponse('response');
});

var iframePort; another function

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    iframePort = port;
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, port) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
    port.postMessage('from-popup');
});

render(
  <App/>,
  window.document.getElementById("app-container")
);
```

**popup.html**

```
  <div id="app-container">
    <iframe width="500" height="500" src="https://app.com"></iframe>
  </div>
```

**Update**

**structure folders**

```
//src
    //js
      //background.js
      //options.js
      //popup.js
//background.html
//manifest.json
//content.js
//options.html
//popup.html
```

When I delete

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://*.app.com/*"  ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
}]
```

the extension is loading

Comment: It depends on how that site handles the authentication. If it's cookies, your extension can use chrome.cookies API in the background script or document.cookie in your content script. Add more relevant details to make the question more answerable.

Comment: @wOxxOm  Authentication OAuth 2.0. Access token in local storage. Do you have any materials, examples?

Comment: Materials for accessing localStorage or declaring a content script? Both should be trivial to find.

Comment: Materials, examples how can I use dates from localstorege from another page in chrome extension and automatically log in to the extension

Comment: I doubt anyone could provide those without seeing a more detailed description of your setup.

Comment: @wOxxOm What would you like to know about the settings? What data is needed?

Comment: I don't know what to add to my comments above, because like I said all that info is really easy to find. For example your extension can read localStorage of a tab by using a content script. If the site isn't open in a tab then things may get more complicated, but since I don't know what exactly the problem is I can't just describe all the confusing possibilities.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's the problem. What if the site is not open on the tab? Describe something more. Please.

Comment: You'll have to open the site in an iframe inside your popup ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)) so your content script will be able to read the site's `localStorage` (and send a message to your popup script as shown in the example). The iframe can be hidden and small (style="visibility:hidden;width:1px;height:1px") or maybe even `display:none` but I'm not sure if Chrome/Firefox would load its content in the latter case.

Comment: @wOxxOm  If I add to: "content_scripts": [{
     "matches": ["http: // mypage / *"],
      "permissions": [
       "Storage"
     ]
     "js": ["content.js"],
}], `" matches ": [" http: // mypage / * "],` in content.js I will have access to the token via `chrome.storage.sync.get (['token'], function (result) {
           console.log ('Value currently is' + result.token); `
         }); ?

Comment: If you are using JWT based authentication and keeping your token as cookie or at local storage, you can read both from your extension and use token as your own. I've found an article here, take a look.
[Can I get access to localStorage of site from chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050868/can-i-get-access-to-localstorage-of-site-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: Is the webapplication users "google accounts" or do you handle your own user/DB?
If you use your own DB, just check the DB if X user is logged in when he logs into the extension. Vice Versa. 

When one is logged in, it logs automatically on the other one (require auth on both)

Comment: In your folder structure there is no file named `content.js`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko `content.js` is in the same folder as `manifest.json`. Look, I updated my structure. I see you have experience in `google chrome extension`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I authenticate a user using a chrome extension when he is already logged in in the website the extension is using.

Well this answer is a little broad, but the most common ways to authenticate are usually 2, either via cookies, or via a token signed by the backend that then tells the backend which user he is talking to.

#### For cookies:

If the authentication was done using cookies, then you just need to use either in your extension `chrome.cookies` which will allow you to use in your background script the cookies. Or if the chrome extension is using a content script then you can directly call `document.cookies` to retrieve the authentication cookie.

#### For token authentication:

If you app happens to be using OAuth2 for example, or a similar implementation in which the user is granted an access token and is stored locally to make then authentication agains the API, then you can retrieve it by just calling the location in which the `token` is saved.

If the token is saved in `localStorage` you can use the `get` method to retrieve the information that is kep there. [Here you have more documentation about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
Similarly you could access the `sessionStorage` in case the token is kept there [Also more documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: This does not solve my problem: I wrote that I had an error: `Could not load JavaScript file" content.js "for content script.`

Comment: I thought the question was about authenticating. Which is the file structure of your project? Also, when you bundle the project, is it generating a `content.js` file? Did you try this already? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34555633/4229159

Comment: It doesn't work. When I delete

`"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://*.app.com/*"  ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
}]` the  extension works

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `content.js` is in the same folder as `manifest.json`, or change the path to it within `manifest.json`.

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://*.app.com/*"  ],
    "js": [ "PATH_TO_CONTENT/content.js" ], // Change this line
    "all_frames": true
  }],
```

For checking you're logged in, the answer above is the right one, but it sounds like you're really looking for the answer to why `Could not load JavaScript file` is occurring.

Comment: To go to the next problem 'Am I logged in' I have to solve the first problem.

Comment: In that case, you should try the solution in this answer! It's meant specifically for that problem

Comment: I put content.hs in the same folder as manifest.json. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should put your content.js in the public folder  then add inside
index.html

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/content.js"></script>
```